# Tooltips for datapoints in a scatter chart in javafx 2.2

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I have created a scatter chart in javafx.It consists of five series of data.I added data from an Arraylist.I need to show a tooltip on every datapoint.To add tooltip it says that we need to create a node for every datapoint.How can we do that?

I tried creating node while adding data but i didnot succeed. I also tried accessing data from scatter chart and assigning it to a new series.even that didnot work.Can someone please help me retrieve details or datapoints from a scatter chart and create a node to each datapoint.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Was it [XYChartData.setNode](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Data.html#setNode(javafx.scene.Node)) which did not work?

Answer (score 11):

From the API doc of `XYChart.Data.nodeProperty`: (bold marking by me)

> public final ObjectProperty nodeProperty
>
> The node to display for
>   this data item. You can either create your own node and **set it on the
>   data item before you add the item to the chart**. Otherwise the chart
>   will create a node for you that has the default representation for the
>   chart type. This node will be set as soon as the data is added to the
>   chart. **You can then get it to add mouse listeners etc.** Charts will do
>   their best to position and size the node appropriately, for example on
>   a Line or Scatter chart this node will be positioned centered on the
>   data values position. For a bar chart this is positioned and resized
>   as the bar for this data item.

It should probably be best to let the chart set its default `Node`s and register `Tooltip`s later. Like this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.ScatterChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SO extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        NumberAxis xa = new NumberAxis(0, 10, 1);
        NumberAxis ya = new NumberAxis(0, 100, 10);
        xa.setLabel("x");                
        ya.setLabel("x*x");
        final ScatterChart<Number,Number> chart = new ScatterChart<Number,Number>(xa,ya);
        chart.setTitle("Square");

        XYChart.Series<Number,Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        series1.setName("square");
        for (double x=0; x<10; x++) {
            XYChart.Data<Number, Number> d = new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(x, x*x);
            series1.getData().add(d);
        }

        chart.getData().add(series1);
        Scene scene  = new Scene(chart, 400, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        for (XYChart.Series<Number, Number> s : chart.getData()) {
            for (XYChart.Data<Number, Number> d : s.getData()) {
                Tooltip.install(d.getNode(), new Tooltip(
                        String.format("%2.1f ^ 2 = %2.1f", 
                                d.getXValue().doubleValue(), 
                                d.getYValue().doubleValue())));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Nice article about scatter charts:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/scatter-chart.htm

Answer (score 2):

After adding data to bar chart

```
chart.getData().add(series);
```

add the following snippet to the code

```
for (final Series<String, Number> series : chart.getData()) {
        for (final Data<String, Number> data : series.getData()) {
            Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
            tooltip.setText(data.getYValue().toString());
            Tooltip.install(data.getNode(), tooltip);
        }
    }
```