# Get specific data point in LineChart javafx

Tags: java, json, javafx, charts, linechart

I want to install a tooltip in every data point in a LineChart, the problem is that every data point is added via json and I dont know how to found the data point after it has been added, this is the method I use to add data points:

```
    public static void setDots(ArrayList<Object> dotsArrayList, String name){
    Integer numOfEvents;
    try {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    // get the data
    JSONObject JSON_obj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Diego\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ContenedoresChart\\json_dots.txt"));
    JSONArray dayArray = (JSONArray) JSON_obj.get(name);
    // get the object of the loop
    JSONObject numOfEventsJSON = (JSONObject) dayArray.get(0);

    numOfEvents = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numOfEventsJSON.get("numEventos")));

    if (numOfEvents.equals(1)) {
        JSONObject contenedorArray = (JSONObject) dayArray.get(1); 
      Double fecha = Double.parseDouble((String.valueOf(contenedorArray.get("fecha"))));
      String hora = String.valueOf(contenedorArray.get("hora"));
      String nombre = String.valueOf(contenedorArray.get("nombre"));
      String id = String.valueOf(contenedorArray.get("ID"));
      Object contenedor = new XYChart.Data(fecha, nombre);
      dotsArrayList.add(contenedor);
      if(contenedoresMap.containsKey(id) == false){
          contenedoresMap.put(id, hora);
      } 
    } else {
        int JSON_Object = 1;
        for(int x = 1; x<=numOfEvents; x++){
        String texto_x = String.valueOf(x);
        JSONObject contenedorArray = (JSONObject) dayArray.get(x);
        Double fecha = Double.parseDouble((String.valueOf(contenedorArray.get("fecha"))));
        String hora = String.valueOf(contenedorArray.get("hora"));
        String nombre = String.valueOf(contenedorArray.get("nombre"));
        String id = String.valueOf(contenedorArray.get("ID"));
        Object contenedor = new XYChart.Data(fecha, nombre);
        dotsArrayList.add(contenedor);
        JSON_Object++;
        if(contenedoresMap.containsKey(id) == false)
        contenedoresMap.put(id, hora);
        System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
    } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("hubo un problema con el json");
    }
}
```

basically the json gives the information for X and Y but also gives an id, I want that id to show in the tooltip, is there an easier way to achieve this? It is very complicated for a simple tooltip

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on what you are asking, but is this a duplicate of: [Tooltips for datapoints in a scatter chart in javafx 2.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117867/tooltips-for-datapoints-in-a-scatter-chart-in-javafx-2-2)?

Comment: It was more like how to get the XYChart.Data object to set the extraValue but I figured it out, thanks anyway!

Comment: As you have figured out the answer, please post it as a [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).